# Configurar la misma dirección IP en 2 tarjetas de red en Windows

Tags: red

Tengo un problema al conectar el cable de red a la base y no tengo conexión.

Ya que en la configuración de entrada de Ethernet del portátil tengo una IP y una puerta de enlace configurada, al conectar el portátil a la base me aparece una nueva configuración de red y no es posible asignarle la misma configuración a ella.

Comment: ¿Podrias ser más concreto?  ¿Que es para ti un dock? hardware? modelo/fabricante?  ¿de que sistema operativo estamos hablando? si te cambia la ip sera porque lo tienes en DHCP en lugar de IP fija en tu configuracion supongo... pero tengo mis dudas porque no se a que te refieres con lo del dock de red... tampoco entiendo el titulo de la pregunta

Comment: Imagino que te refieres a un portátil que permite la conexión de una base con extensión de puertos (USB, ethernet, HDMI, etc), ¿cierto? En ese caso al conectar el portátil a la base aparece una nueva interfaz de red y quieres que esa nueva interfaz tenga la misma IP que la que tiene la interfaz integrada del portátil. Windows no permite configurar la misma dirección IP a más de una interfaz, pero te permite configurar una interfaz "puente" en la que agregas ambas interfaces físicas y al configurar la IP en la interfaz puente podrás usar la misma IP en ambos interfaces físicos.

Comment: Si ese es tu problema, nómbrame en tu respuesta (con el símbolo @) e indícame si necesitas que redacte una respuesta con las instrucciones de cómo realizar esa tarea.

Comment: Si @OscarGarcia, me refería a ese problema. Te agradeceria que me indicaras como podria resolverlo correctamente.

Comment: Voy a tener que ayudarte un poco a ciegas, tengo el portátil en la oficina y si creo la interfaz de puente para ilustrarte cómo hacerlo perderé la conexión con él. Intentaré hacerlo por comentarios, aunque lo ideal sería que tuvieras suficiente reputación para usar el chat de stackoverflow.

Comment: ¿Esa PC se conecta en otra red (ejemplo, el trabajo) y ahora quieres conectarla en casa? Si es así, puede ser que en el trabajo se usa IP estática y en casa se usa DHCP. Entra a la [configuración de Red](https://www.adslzone.net/esenciales/windows-10/direccion-ip-windows-10/) y anota los valores que hay. Luego selecciona *Obtener una dirección IP automáticamente* y ya debe conectar en casa. En el caso contrario, que esté en DHCP y necesitas una config IP estática, tendrás que contactar al administrador del sistema.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para poder usar la misma dirección IP fija en dos interfaces de red es necesario unir ambas interfaces con un puente de red. De este modo el tráfico saliente tendrá la misma dirección IP salga el tráfico por la interfaz que salga.

El procedimiento para crear una interfaz puente entre dos interfaces existentes es la siguiente:

- Abrimos un terminal de PowerShell como Administrador.
- Tecleamos la instrucción `Get-NetAdapter` para que nos muestre los adaptadores de red que tenemos.
- Tecleamos `New-NetswitchTeam -Name "Nombre para el puente" -TeamMembers "Adaptador 1", "Adaptador 2"`.
- Por último tecleamos `Get-NetswitchTeam` para comprobar que se ha realizado la tarea correctamente.

Comment: Buena respuesta, no olvides marcarla como correcta. Por cierto, hay que abrir powershell como administrador, ¿verdad?